# Is 'List' a leaky abstraction?

Tags: c, abstraction, encapsulation, list

> **Abstraction** - Creates barrier between representation & usage of `List` ADT
>
> **Encapsulation** - Ensures maintaining in-variants of `List` ADT.
>     An *invariant* is a fact about a data structure that is always true (assuming the code is bug-free), no matter what functions are called by user.

With this understanding, below is the user code,

```
/***** main.c *****/


#include"list.h"

int main(void){

  List *arrayList = createList((List *)NULL, CREATE_NEW_LIST);


  if (arrayList == (List *)0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create list \n");
    exit(1); //Nothing else to do without arrayList
  }

  // Objects should only be on heap
  int *object1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object1 = 777;
  insertItem(arrayList, object1);

  int *object2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object2 = 888;
  insertItem(arrayList, object2);

/*


  List *linkedList = createList((List *)NULL, CREATE_NEW_LIST);

  if (linkedList == (List *)0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create list \n");
    exit(1); //Nothing else to do without linked list
  }

  // Objects should only be on heap
  int *object1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object1 = 777;
  insertItem(arrayList, object1);

  int *object2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object2 = 888;
  insertItem(arrayList, object2);

*/
}
```

---

below is the `List` ADT,

```
/************ list.h ************/

/*
   List is an ordered collection of homogenuous type elements(unique or duplicate).
   List is not designed to have collection of heterogenuous type elements
   All elements in a List are related.
   List is mutable
   Each element has a position.
   If an element is deleted, then still the remaining elements sit in new order.

   Array implementation of List
   Linked implementation of List
*/

#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

/*********************** Usage - start ****************/ 
typedef enum{false, true}bool;
typedef enum {CREATE_NEW_LIST, DOUBLE_THE_LIST, HALF_THE_LIST}Op;

#if defined(ARRAY)

  /* To ensure Encapsultation(i.e., maintain invariants of array) */
  typedef struct List List;

#elif defined(LINKED_LIST)

  /* To ensure Encapsultation(i.e., maintain invariants of linked list) */
  /* User will not get access to list node */
  typedef struct List List;


#else
  #error "Wrong list implementation macro name !!!"
#endif


void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);
void deleteItem(List *, int listIndex);
List* createList(List *, Op opType);
/*********************** Usage - end ****************/
```

---

Below is array implementation,

```
/***************** arrayImple.c **************/

#if defined(ARRAY)

#include"list.h"


/************ Representation - start ************/
typedef struct List{
  void **array;

  /* Following members for Housekeeping - Array enhancement*/
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;

#define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
/********************* Representation - end ************/





/************* Usage - start ***************/
List *createList(List *list, Op opType){

   if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    list->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));


    /* Is it safe to initialise zero to  array of  pointers? */
    list->array = memset(list->array, 0, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = -1;
    list->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
  }else if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, 2*(list->size)*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    list->size = 2*(list->size);
  }else if(opType == HALF_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, ((list->size)/2)*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;
    list->size = (list->size)/2;
  }

  return list;

}

void insertItem(List *arrayList, void *newItem){

  /* House keeping - Enhance the array */
  if(arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1 == arrayList->size){
    arrayList = createList(arrayList, DOUBLE_THE_LIST);
  }


  /* Insert new element - O(1) operation */
  arrayList->array[++(arrayList->lastItemPosition)] = newItem;


  return;
}

void deleteItem(List *arrayList, int listIndex){

  void * element = arrayList->array[listIndex];
  free(element);

  /* Delete operation - O(n) operation */
  for(int accumulator = listIndex; accumulator <= arrayList->lastItemPosition; accumulator++){
    arrayList->array[accumulator] = arrayList->array[++accumulator];
  }
  arrayList->lastItemPosition--;


  /* House keeping - Half the list */
  if(arrayList->size > INITIAL_LIST_SIZE){ /* Minimum size maintained */
    if((arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1) == ((arrayList->size)/2)){
      arrayList = createList(arrayList, HALF_THE_LIST);
    }
  }
  return;

}
/******************** Usage - end *******************/

#endif
```

---

Below is the linked list implementation,

```
/**********linkedListImpl.c ***********/

#if defined(LINKED_LIST)

#include"list.h"

/***************** Representation - start ******************/
  typedef struct DListNode{

    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  }DListNode;

  /*
    Reason to introduce 'List' type:

    Problem 1:
     Say, user code has 'x' and 'y' pointing to the same shopping list that is built using 'Node' type.
     Some part of user code update list with new item using 'x'
     'y' is not in sync with this updation
        Node *x = someCreatedList;
        Node *y = x;
        Node *z = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        z->next = x;
        x = z; //y misses that reference.
    Solution:
     Maintain a List type, whose job is to point to head(first node) of the list.
     User code will go via reference of List type


    Problem 2:
     It make sense to have references of 'Node' type pointing to NULL
     Applying operation[insertItem()] on NULL pointer will cause runtime errors
    Solution:
     Run operations over List type because it does not make sense to have reference of SList type pointing to NULL.

    To solve problem1 & problem2, here is 'List' type
  */

typedef struct List{ /* Circular linked list(prev, next) */

  DListNode *head;
  int size; /*size attribute is not part of list definition, but quick way to help user code */
  }List;

#define SENTINEL_NODE_DATA_ITEM (void *)0

 /*
 The following invariants apply to the `linkedList` with a sentinel.
(1) For any linkedList d, d.head != null. (There’s always a sentinel.)
(2) For any DListNode x, x.next != null.
(3) For any DListNode x, x.prev != null.
(4) For any DListNode x, if x.next == y, then y.prev == x.
(5) For any DListNode x, if x.prev == y, then y.next == x.
(6) A `linkedList`’s "size" variable is the number of DListNodes, NOT
   COUNTING the sentinel (denoted by "head"), that can be accessed from the    
   sentinel by a sequence of "next" references.
 */
/************ Representation - end *************/






/********** Helper function - start ***********/
DListNode* createNode(void * value){

  DListNode *newNode= malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

  newNode->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = newNode;
  newNode->item = value;

  return newNode;
}
/******** Helper function - end ********/










/******** Usage - start **********/
List *createList(List *list, Op opType ){

  List *listPointer = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    /*
      Amidst performing insert/delete operations on 'List',

      To reduce the number of special checks, we designate one node as 'SENTINEL'

      After using sentinel, there will be no NULL assignments/check in code.
    */

    DListNode *sentinel = createNode(SENTINEL_NODE_DATA_ITEM);


    listPointer->head = sentinel;
    listPointer->head->next = listPointer->head;
    listPointer->head->prev = listPointer->head;
    listPointer->size = 0;

    return listPointer;
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid flag passed to createList() \n");
    return (List *)0;
  }


}


        /* O(1) operation - insert() operation */
void insertItem(List *linkedList, void *newItem){

  DListNode *newNode = createNode(newItem);

  if(linkedList->size == 0){

    linkedList->head->next = linkedList->head->prev = newNode;

  }else{

    /* Link with current last node in the linked list*/
    newNode->prev = linkedList->head->prev;
    linkedList->head->prev->next = newNode;

    /* Link with Sentinel node */
    newNode->next = linkedList->head;
    linkedList->head->prev = newNode;
  }

  return;
}

       /* O(n) - delete() operation*/
void deleteItem(List *linkedList, int listIndex){

  int accumulator = 0;
  DListNode *nodeToDelete = linkedList->head->next;

  if(listIndex < linkedList->size){

     while(accumulator++ < listIndex){
      nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete->next;
     }
     nodeToDelete->prev->next = nodeToDelete->next;
     nodeToDelete->next->prev = nodeToDelete-> prev;

     free(nodeToDelete);
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "deleteItem() - Invalid Index");
  }


  return;
}
/********** Usage - end *************/

#endif
```

---

Compilation procedure:

`gcc -DLINKED_LIST main.c linkedListImpl.c`

or

`gcc -DARRAY main.c arrayImpl.c`

---

1)

Does `List` ensure Encapsulation?

2)

Is `List` a good abstraction? If it leaks, then please clarify

*Note: Motivation - To understand Abstraction & Encapsulation, using C*

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Where are you stuck? What do you suspect?

Comment: (walls of code are discouraged here)

Comment: @AndresF. Am yet to confirm whether  code ensures Encapsulation

Comment: `typedef struct List List` written twice in `list.h`.

Answer (score 5):

A leaky abstraction is an abstraction, for example an abstract data type (ADT), where the users of it need to know something about the internal details to be able to correctly use that ADT.

To some extent, nearly all abstractions are leaky, but some are worse than others.
Your `List` ADT leaks the information/requirement that all elements of the list must be allocated on the heap. This is not a real serious leak and others might argue that it is not a leak at all.
Apart from that does your `List` ADT not leak any other implementation details. In particular, the user of `List` is completely unaware if the elements are internally stored in an array or in a linked list. That detail is properly abstracted away.

---

As for encapsulation, other than the requirement to pass heap-allocated elements, there is no way for an outsider to mess with the `List` ADT. This means that `List` is properly encapsulated, or at least to the extent that is convenient in C.
A fully encapsulated `List` would also handle the memory allocation for the elements stored in it, so that the users don't have to think about it, but that brings quite a lot of complications with it in C.

Comment: Yes, others would argue that the memory requirement isn't a leak. If you have data you have to store it somewhere. That's not specific to any particular data structure or abstraction thereof.

Comment: What about Encapsulation?

Comment: @overexchange: See my edit

Answer (score 3):

It has already been said, but it's worth saying again: All abstractions are leaky.

But some offenders are worse than others and the List abstraction is pretty good. One thing that does leak is the performance of the different implementations: Array-based lists for example can read a single element in O(1) while a simple linked list implementation would have a O(n) worst case because one has to hop through the whole list the get to the last element.
That's usually not considered too bad a leak because these performance differences are the reason why we use different list implementations at all. If they would all perform equally well there would be no need to use different implementations and hide them behind a common abstraction.

Comment: What about Encapsulation? Does the code make sense?

Comment: "All abstractions are leaky" is one of those sayings (popularized by Spolsky) which intuitively seem true but which have no demonstration. I'd be wary of repeating them blindly :)

Comment: @AndresF.: There's another saying, "the devil is in the details". Abstractions are a way of hiding the details, but the devils still lurk about. [The dragon of numerical error](https://accu.org/index.php/articles/1702) is one such demonstration.

Comment: @whatisname Sure. It's hard to prove informal sayings, unfortunately. Examples don't help with universal quantifiers. Spolsky's assertion is intuitively true, but hasn't been shown to be universally true (at least, not in Spolsky's terms). I'm just saying we as programmers should be careful when blindly asserting this kind of things as gospel.

Comment: @overexchange How about this: We think of it as a prediction instead. Then we can say in keeping with the scientific method that it hasn't been falsified yet. (At least to my knowledge it hasn't; please give an example of a non-leaky abstraction if you know some)